# Loading dynamic PHP echo in webpage without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, php, database

I have the PHP code where I get echo as my postgres database table fields I want to  display these fields in my html and JavaScript based web application.for now I can load them in my webpage but I have to reload the webpage to get newly updated values. I want to get them automatically in a textbox without reloading application.i read that an ajax request would be helpful
given is the php code i am using with html to show case records but i have to reload page every time to get it updated

```
<?php
   $host        = "host = localhost";
   $port        = "port = 5432";
   $dbname      = "dbname = geoserver";
   $credentials = "user = postgres password=password";

   $db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );

   $sql =<<<EOF
      SELECT * from audit.logged_actions
      ORDER BY action_tstamp_tx DESC 
      LIMIT 5;

EOF;

   $ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
   if(!$ret) {
      echo pg_last_error($db);
      exit;
   } 
   while($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) {
     // echo "e = ". $row[1] . "\n";  

     echo "<input type='text' value='$row[14] '/>"; 


      echo "<input type='text' value='$row[13] '/>";
   }
   echo "Operation done successfully\n";
   pg_close($db);
?>
```

Comment: Please include any code attempts you've made at solving the problem in your question.

Comment: I hope you want to update part of your webpage for database changes. This can be achieved through ajax, but it requires a lot of effort writing code.Node.js with Socket.io, you can simply achieve this using polling mechanism. I don't have some examples to show you but can share some resources. Check http://darrenoneill.co.uk/post/real-time-web-apps-postgresql-and-node/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that after your browser renders the output of your php script, it is not connected to your php anymore. This is how HTTP works.

To be able to show the output without refreshing the whole page, you need to use javascript to make another HTTP request to your PHP script.

Something like this:

```
<?php
$host        = "host = localhost";
$port        = "port = 5432";
$dbname      = "dbname = geoserver";
$credentials = "user = postgres password=password";

$db = pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );

$sql =<<<EOF
    SELECT * from audit.logged_actions
    ORDER BY action_tstamp_tx DESC 
    LIMIT 5;

EOF;

$ret = pg_query($db, $sql);
if(!$ret) {
  echo pg_last_error($db);
  exit;
} 
?>
<div id='content'>
  <?php while($row = pg_fetch_row($ret)) { ?>
    <input type='text' value='<?= $row[14] ?>'/> 
    <input type='text' value='<?= $row[13] ?>'/>
  <?php } ?>

  Operation done successfully

  <script>
    (function() {
      const secondsToRefresh = 5;
      const Http = new XMLHttpRequest();
      const url='#YOUR_PHP_SCRIPT_URL#';
      setTimeout(function() {
        Http.open("GET", url);
        Http.send();
      }, secondsToRefresh * 1000);
      Http.onreadystatechange=(e)=>{
        document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = Http.responseText;
      }
    })()
  </script>
</div>";
```

Comment: I tested this code with my application but still does not solves my problem as it is giving me same result as before.